# Bare Arch Linux with temporary X server for applications

Tags: command-line, graphics, window

Not sure if this is the right place to post this question, but I'm pretty confident that it will interest some people here.

I am a pretty big CLI user, what I mean by this is that 90% of my workflow is between emacs, tmux and mc. My only use of GUIs and graphical systems is with games and internet browsing (which I work out in Lynx very often).

Since I am bored of fancy interfaces and graphical configuration, I was thinking about just using a command line TTY on my everyday operations, and starting a X Server when I launch an application.

I would like to be able to run a program (let says dwarffortress in 2D Mode) directly from the command-line in order to start a X Server (if using Xorg), and make this server stop when the application is killed.

In my research I stumbed upon some manual running of the .xinit file and it is not exactly what I need (since the .xinit need to specify the running program, and it is not as transparent as I would it to be).

Any advice ?

I don't know if I'm clear with my intentions, hope it does, if not I'll be happy to answers questions.

*EDIT: I indicated "Arch Linux" in the title since it is the base of what I am willing to setup*

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-x-applications-without-a-desktop-or-a-wm

Comment: Thanks I already seeen that, I was looking for better solution than having to launch my applications with the xinit command/file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an X window manager, simply, without using graphical environment? the startup system will always be started when you want and need it with `startx`.

My case is similar, but the `tty` is very small and dysfunctional for me, since many times I need to have several terminal sessions in the same view, or have a quick change between them.

I solve this with a window manager as I have told you, I have used `AwesomeWM` for years and currently I use `dwm`.

Comment: Thanks ! I was curious about using a tiling WM, I'm gonna try to setup something convenient with dwm.